# How to Remove the "Loading Next Set of Posts" Loading Image and "Congrats you've reached the end of the internet." From Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll, infinite

So here's the code for infinite scroll on my blog. It works fine and everything, save for I don't want the part where it shows the gif for "Loading next set of posts." And the end where it says "Congrats you've reached the end of the internet." To show up because it's clunky and annoying.

```
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/u2vm2hxv6/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var $container = $('#entries');
    $container.infinitescroll({
        itemSelector: '#posts',
        navSelector: '#pagination',
        nextSelector: '#pagination a',
        loadingImg: '',
        loadingText: '',
        bufferPx: 3000
    },
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
        $newElems.find('.photo-slideshow').pxuPhotoset({
            lightbox: true,
            rounded: 'corners',
            gutter: '3px',
            borderRadius: '0px',
            photoset: '.photo-slideshow',
            photoWrap: '.photo-data',
            photo: '.pxu-photo'
        });
    });

    });
    </script>
```

I asked someone else how to possibly fix this and they sent me here, https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll/wiki/Options . I toyed around with the options shown, but I wasn't able to get it working how I wanted it.

Help much appreciated. Thanks. (I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to javascript.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using the v1 properties but using v2 of the plugin, the v2 properties are on the URL you have provided https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll/wiki/Options, which will be some combination of the below, its difficult to tell from Docs how the work so you will need to experiment but start with:

```
finished: false
finishedMsg: '',
img:'',
msg:false
msgText:''
```

rather than:

```
loadingImg: '',
loadingText: '',
```